# Why is Ansible converting lists to strings?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Ansible is unexpectedly converting lists to strings when merging lists, can someone help me explain why?

The playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list1:
      - aaa: 'aaa'
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        a: 'asdfg'
    - set_fact:
        list2: "{{ list1|d([]) + [ hostvars['localhost']['a']] }}"
    - debug: var=list2
    - set_fact:
        list3: "{{ list1|d([]) + [ hostvars['localhost']['undefined variable']] }}"
    - debug: var=list3
```

and this is the play result (unnecessary parts omited):

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 05 September 2018  09:52:31 +0200 (0:00:00.071)       0:00:00.203 ***
ok: [localhost] => {
    "list2": [
        {
            "aaa": "aaa"
        },
        "asdfg"
    ]
}

...

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 05 September 2018  09:52:31 +0200 (0:00:00.085)       0:00:00.345 ***
ok: [localhost] => {
    "list3": "[{'aaa': 'aaa'}, Undefined]"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The second debug task outputs string instead of expected dict. Is this a correct behavior I just don't understand or should I file a bug?

Comment: Sorry I edited the wrong title. The question is about list3 being a string instead of a list.

Comment: I don't follow. The latter example outputs a string, not a list. It's obvious from the output; and proved by debugging `list3.0` being `[` instead of `{'aaa': 'aaa'}`

Comment: According to https://blog.crisp.se/2016/10/20/maxwenzin/how-to-append-to-lists-in-ansible, the `+` sign should merge two lists together; that is expectedly done in the first example, and should behave the same in the second case, when it creates a string instead of a list. That's what I don't understand, or misunderstand, and seeking for a clarification.

Comment: You ask "*Is this a correct behavior?*" -- please specify what is the correct behaviour you ask about, or otherwise who is to judge, what the correct behaviour in case of an undefined element value in Jinja2 is.　・　I think it would be cleaner if it threw an exception. At least it would cause one less confusion. But someone else decided a missing value should be treated the way it is. Who's correct?

Comment: Maybe you'd understand what's happening, if you defined a variable called `Undefined: foo` and check the result. It might also be useful if you'd understand that Jinja2 expression produces a string, nothing else; always a string. Anything that you see as an object is an effect of interpreting a string returned by Jinja2.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to improve the question at the end of the post. The reason I'm not creating an issue in Ansible's Github page is that I don't believe they will ever react :)

Answer (score 4):

<sup>This answer describes the state of things in Ansible up to 2.6.x. There is a [movement](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/32738) to support [native Python objects](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/nativetypes/) in Ansible v2.7.</sup>

---

> Why is Ansible converting lists to strings?

Ansible is **not** converting any list to a string in your example.

---

Ansible gets data:

1. from YAML parser

   These can be: a list, a dictionary, a scalar (string, Boolean, or numerical value).
2. from other sources (for example: Jinja2, inventory, CLI extravars)

   Any data coming from other sources is **a string**.

---

As Jinja2 always returns a string, you can calculate the result in your head and pass the value as YAML quoted scalar (interpreted by Ansible as a string):

- The first task above is equivalent to:

  ```
  - set_fact:
      list2: "[{'aaa': 'aaa'}, 'asdfg']"
  ```

  Ansible gets **a string** (not a list) and tries to interpret it. It finds a JSON string matching a list and creates a list object.
- The second task is equivalent to:

  ```
  - set_fact:
      list3: "[{'aaa': 'aaa'}, Undefined]"
  ```

  What you observe here is Jinja2 replacing a list with an element with an undefined value with a string `Undefined` (and not quoting that string).

  Ansible gets **a string** and tries to interpret it. It does not find a proper data structure<sup>*</sup> and creates a string object.

---

<sup>*</sup> There is a special case if a variable called `Undefined` existed, then Ansible would replace the unquoted `Undefined` with that variable value and create a list object.

Comment: That seems like a bad design for me, tough, because 1) That is not an expected behavior for whoever writes the code (the expected is it to be a `None` object, or any equivalent to a javascript `null`). 2) Handling those cases can be trick (and you have to remember to handle them whenever you have a loop that appends an object to an array). It still seems more like a bug to me, at least from a DX point-of-view, but maybe that is not something easily fixed, probably because Ansible throws an error when a `None` value is accessed by default (even without trying to access its children).